# Arduino Serial Monitor shows strange ASCII characters

Tags: arduino, usb, ftdi

I connected an ArduiMU v3+ via a FTDI-cable to my Mac (OS X 10.10) (latest VC FTDI driver is installed and loaded).

Inside the Arduino-software the Serial Monitor (monitoring /dev/cu.usbserial-AJ038NZ3) shows 
a lot of weird ASCII characters. 
What could be the reason for this problem?

[image]

Comment: What baud rate is the arduino using? A mismatch there is a common cause of that sort of output. Looks like you've got the monitor set to 115200.

Comment: I don't know but I tried ALL baud-rates available and its always the same.

Comment: To be clear, you've tried the same baud rate that the arduino sketch is using?

Comment: @Hedge can you post the code you're using to get the Serial output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Arduino Serial Monitor, use OS X's ability to determine the baud rate automatically.  Whenever, I use my FTDI cable, I monitor the input using the `screen` command.

In this case you can grep for the name of the device:

`ls /dev | grep tty\.[Uu]sb | awk '{print "/dev/"$1}' | xargs screen`

check out `man screen` for a bit more background.

or use the simple version by finding the name of the port in the `/dev` folder then using

`screen <name_of_FTDI>`